# Why does the position step size change after each render, even though the step value never changes? ( three.js)

Tags: three.js

I have a very simple cube mesh:

```
var playerGeo = new THREE.BoxGeometry(5,5,5);
var playerMat = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xFF1865});
var player = new THREE.Mesh(playerGeo, playerMat);
player.position.x = 0;
player.position.y = -50;
scene.add(player);
```

and in my render function (which uses reqestAnimationFrame) i have the following code which is meant to move the cube left/right based on wether the user presses the left/right key.

```
 $("body").keydown(function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode == 37) {
            player.position.x -= 0.01;
        }else if(e.keyCode == 39){
            player.position.x += 0.01;
        }
    });
```

This works. However I noticed slightly weird behaviour, as at first if I press the left key, the cube will go left a tiny amount (what seems to be 0.01), but after quite a few times of pressing the arrow keys the distance in which the cube goes on each press seems to slowly increase. So the first time i press a left/right key, the cube will move left/right about a mm. Within about 10 presses left or right, it moves about a cm each press. 
What is going on?

Please ask if you require more info!

Thanks

Comment: can you create a fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am suspecting the position change is ok, but your projection is deformed

query the position after change for example open console and add

```
console.log("position before"+player.position.x);
if(e.keyCode == 37) {
    player.position.x -= 0.01;
}else if(e.keyCode == 39){
   player.position.x += 0.01;
}
console.log("position after"+player.position.x);
```

check if the change is 0.01 as planned

if it is and you are using perspective camera you have to set field of vision correctly to avoid fisheye effect

if neither of these are the the cause you have to provide more information...